# Explanation of Techan.js chart.accessor() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, charts

I am currently working on a project that uses the [Techan.js](http://techanjs.org/) library for producing financially-oriented charts (based on [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)).

As of reading through the example shown [here](http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/27c4a333b0e0813e093d) for creating a candlestick chart, I've managed to replicate most of the steps in my own code, but after extensive searching I still did not find an explanation for how `candlestick.accessor()` works. Is it a get method? A set method? I simply do not understand its purpose and how to work with it.

The developer also seems to use this in his draw function:

```
y.domain(techan.scale.plot.ohlc(data, candlestick.accessor()).domain());
```

From this, I can deduce that he's assigning *something* to the chart's **y** domain, but what is that? What does `techan.scale.plot.ohlc(data, candlestick.accessor()).domain())` do? Does it create a whole new OHLC plot that it then accesses using the same accessor used before?

The API reference hardly contains any information explaining the `accessor()` method, and I can't figure out how it interacts with the chart, or *a* chart.

If someone has any experience with Techan.js, I'd like to ask for an explanation of the `.accessor()` method. Thank you very much.